# Why can i only write non-numeric characters with this regex code

Tags: c#, regex

maybe it is really a small mistake but i can't find it.

```
private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+$");
    e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
}
```

I can only write non-numeric characters in my input and i don't understand why?

**Update**

Here some more information:

I am making a wpf program in the xaml i put:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox" PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="8" Margin="133,74,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112" Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"/>
```

so and after that i made the void

```
private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+$");
    e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
}
```

**Update 2**

Found another solution but only the minus sign at the beginning is not working correctly, i tried different ways but i am not pro in regex and don't know how to fix.

```
        private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("^[.][0-9]+$|^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$");
        e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch((sender as TextBox).Text.Insert((sender as TextBox).SelectionStart, e.Text));
    }
```

**update 3**
new version of the regex line:

```
^[-+]{0,1}[0-9]*[.,]{0,1}[0-9]{0,4}$
```

only problems occuring now is that it can start with a comma or a dot and that the minus can be followed up by a comma

Comment: [I can't reproduce your problem](https://regex101.com/r/qwylGL/1), can you post a demo of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

This seems reliable, you could probably use regex as well

```
private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{

   if (!(sender is TextBox textBox))
   {
      return;
   }

   // use SelectionStart property to find the caret position
   // insert the previewed text into the existing text in the textbox
   var text = textBox.Text.Insert(textBox.SelectionStart, e.Text);

   if(text == "+" || text == "-")
      return;

   // if parsing is successful, set Handled to false
   e.Handled =  !double.TryParse(text, out var _) ;
}
```

**Original Answer**

You have currently programmed, if its a number then handle the event, I.e stop Processing here.

You need to invert the logic

```
private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+$");
    // if its not matched then Handle the event
    // so it never gets to the display
    e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
}
```

**Update**

I use this pattern

```
^[-+]?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$
```

**Exmaple**

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[-+]?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$");
Console.WriteLine("Allowed  = " + regex.IsMatch("123"));
Console.WriteLine("Allowed  = " + regex.IsMatch("12.3"));
Console.WriteLine("Allowed  = " + regex.IsMatch(".123"));
Console.WriteLine("Allowed  = " + regex.IsMatch("+.123"));
Console.WriteLine("Allowed  = " + regex.IsMatch("00123"));
Console.WriteLine("Allowed  = " + regex.IsMatch("1.2.3"));
Console.WriteLine("Allowed  = " + regex.IsMatch("12..3"));
Console.WriteLine("Allowed  = " + regex.IsMatch("+123"));
Console.WriteLine("Allowed  = " + regex.IsMatch("+-1123"));
```

**Output**

```
Allowed  = True
Allowed  = True
Allowed  = False
Allowed  = False
Allowed  = True
Allowed  = False
Allowed  = False
Allowed  = True
Allowed  = False
```

[**Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kKW7yq)

Comment: ahh that fixed it. But one other problem occured, i can type the "-" and the "." more than 1 time. But it is allowed to be typed 0 or 1 time.

Comment: yes the one I gave in the beginning is also working on the demo website, same as your last one. But after the inversion with this one: "^[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+$ i can type many "-"and "." and with your code i can only type numbers. So the inversion is doing something weird haha

Comment: @bamischijf ahh ok i see the problem, these validate a number, not validate input, which will give you potentially malformed numbers. ill see if i can find a better solution

Comment: pff still some problems. Because the Comma is correct and can be typed one time. But the dot can still be typed more than one time. I also found another solution with regex but only there the minus and plus are not integrated further is everything oke. See edit

Comment: @bamischijf parse double wouldn't allow multiple periods. and this works 100% fine in wpf. can you give an example of a number that you can type multiope periods

Comment: For commas is working great but when making use of a dot after a number i can type it multiple times? maybe something to do with numerical/decimal keyboard?

Comment: Also found a better version of the regex, but the only problems occuring now is that it can start with a comma or a dot and that the minus can be followed up by a comma. see update 3

Comment: @bamischijf `^[+-]{0,1}$|[.][0-9]+$|^[-+]?\d*(.)$|^[-+]?\d*(.\d+)?$`

Comment: I got it!! Your or part in the beginning gave me a new idea! This one is working:)  ^[+-]{0,1}$|^[-+]{0,1}[0-9]{1,}[.,]{0,1}[0-9]$

Comment: the /d matches the plus as well i didnt realize this. anyway im glad its working